# Retrieve JSON object key names in Github Action

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have a composite github action that I'm using to retrieve vault secrets and perform a replacement in my appsettings. My data will come in as json which I convert to JSON object using [fromJson](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.3/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) built-in github function. It does not seem like bash can traverse an object so I'm trying to load keys and values in 2 separate arrays and traverse them in a for loop. I need to convert the json object into an array of the key names so that I can perform a replacement in the subsequent steps. It seems when I do jsonObject.* it just returns an array of the values. Is there anyway I can get the key names of the json object as an array? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
- name: Test Json
  run: echo "TESTJSON={\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: bash

- name: Replace Vault Tokens
  run: |
    vaultKeys=(${{join(fromJson(env.TESTJSON), ' ')}}) #need a way here to reference the key names
    vaultValues=(${{join(fromJson(env.TESTJSON).*, ' ')}}) #this works for the value case
    for index in ${!vaultValues[@]}
    do
      echo "${vaultKeys[$index]}"
      echo "${vaultValues[$index]}"
    done
  shell: bash
```

Comment: Have you tried using `jq`? It should be already installed on github hosted runners.